# How to get the directory of the .exe for a Node.js pkg executable?

Tags: node.js, windows, exe

I'm compiling/building a Node.js project into an .exe using Vercel's `pkg` but I'm trying to find where that executable file is during the program's runtime. To clarify, I want the Node.js program to know where the .exe file it is being run from is, to confirm it is correctly installed.

**Context:**
I cannot guarantee where the user has the .exe stored the first time they run it, but I want it to copy itself to the AppData folder so I can setup a Windows service from it, if it's not being run from there already. This in hopes of making a self-installing program, that doesn't require me to build an installed around it.

So on it's first run, I need the location of the .exe to be able to copy where I want. I might just have not picked it up, but I can't find an answer on either the pkg documentation or on another question here.

**What I've Tried:** I have tried `process.cwd`, `process.pkg`, `__filename`, `__dirname` and so on, but they all lead to the wrong thing, usually the `snapshot` folder of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to the main script it's as simple as finding it:

```
process.argv
```

From the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

Pkg from Vercel, is not an installer, its just a packager that will package node binaries and your code in a single exe.

You can follow this tutorial that shows [how to make an installer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W96jcUh9-bg) it even enables you to set a path of where you want your exe to be installed

Comment: That returns as `C:\snapshot\Client\index.js` which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: When you run your .exe file it returns C:\snapshot\Client\index.js?

Comment: Here are the steps I'm proceeding with:

1- writing an index.js file that has console.log(process.arv[1]);
2- running the command: pkg .
3- moving the .exe file that was produced to another directory
4- running the .exe file
5- a prompt pops up showing the location of the .exe file

Is it that you do the same things I did, but you get a different result?
Or, is it not what you are looking for ?

Comment: Just checked and it's actually my argv[0] when I run the program, but I plan to filter all my argv with .exe, to ensure it doesn't change position from any cause. If you update your answer to say it's inside the argv, I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: Glad you found a solution :D